# Execute Batch in Remote Powershell Session that Requires Interactive/Redirection

Tags: powershell, remoting

My company uses an Oracle based product called "Hyperion". I believe Oracle hired some high school students to write the batch files to start and stop the services. The problem I have is that I would like to use Powershell Remoting to execute a batch file called "Stop_Hyperion.bat" which is provided by Oracle for the purposes of stopping several processes and services in a controlled manner. Unfortunately for me this doesn't work:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName HyperionServer1 -Credential $PSCredential
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {C:\Scripts\Stop_Hyperion.bat}
```

It executes the batch file, but the batch file contains a command called "Timeout" which generates the following error:

```
ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Input re...ss immediately.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : HYPERIONSERVER1
```

If I use good old PSExec, I get the same error unless I use the -i option for a desktop interactive session. Is there some way to accomplish that kind of interactive session with PSSession?

I would have modified the batch file or just stopped the services using Powershell commands, but the batch files contain call to other batch files (which also use Timeout), which contain even more calls. There are so many nested calls that it would take quite awhile to unravel exactly what the batch files are doing.

Comment: Perhaps you can replace 'timeout' with a script or mock executable that does nothing?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be practical. If I was going to modify the batch files, I would just go ahead and write the powershell script to do what they are doing. Unfortunately the batch scripts are not simple, there are a lot of nested calls to other batch files, and many of those also contain the timeout command.

Comment: `@()|C:\Scripts\Stop_Hyperion.bat`?

Comment: I did not mean to alter the batch files, as they are a given. I meant that to me be able to replace the 'timeout.exe' on your system, so that when a batch file calls timeout.exe, your version get's called instead.

Comment: See also https://erichelmer.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/are-you-still-manually-starting-services/

Answer (score 1):

Using `Enter-PSSession localhost`, I can't get a BAT file to use `timeout`. File `a.bat`:

```
timeout 5 >NUL
echo %errorlevel% > C:\Users\my_user\abc.txt
```

But, by running `Start-Process .\a.bat -wait` then I can see `timeout` correctly waits, and returns exit code 0. With a little more .NET you should be able to get the stdout if needed.

I think this works by spawning the CMD process with its own new STDIN as if it was in a new conhost window (instead of reusing the powershell process STDIN which cannot be redirected).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the batch files, and create a native PowerShell implementation as replacement.

'Stop-Service' and 'Start-Service' are standard cmdlets available on Windows.

This may ignore some of the complexity in the supplied batch files, but if it gets the job done, it is sufficient. This is the same as stopping and starting a service from the services manager.